# Efficient way of creating a matrix in numpy by duplicating a given array along a diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have some array that I already know, say:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

I also know that I want a matrix of some size that has total length of `length a + some amount n` and width `n+1`, like so:

```
n = 4
length = len(a) + n
width = n + 1
```

I'm looking to create an array that looks like this:

```
array([[1,2,3,0,0,0,0],
       [0,1,2,3,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,2,3,0,0],
       [0,0,0,1,2,3,0],
       [0,0,0,0,1,2,3]])
```

Unfortunately `numpy.kron` and in general block diagonals are not what I'm looking for, since that would cause the next row to increment by 3 instead of 1.

I have a way of doing it where I can create each row of the matrix by using a for loop and stacking the resulting arrays on top of each other as well as a method where I use `scipy.sparse.diag` to create the array using, again, a for loop, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient method.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982967/7207392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) that gives us `views` into a zeros-padded array and as such are very efficient, both memory-wise and performance-wise -

```
def sliding_windows(a, n=4):
    length = len(a) + n
    width = n + 1
    z_pad = np.zeros(n,dtype=a.dtype)
    ac = np.r_[z_pad, a, z_pad]
    s = ac.strides[0]    
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(ac[n:], shape=(width, length), strides=(-s,s),writeable=False)
```

If you need a writable version, simply make a copy with `sliding_windows(a, n=4).copy()`.

Sample runs -

```
In [42]: a
Out[42]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [43]: sliding_windows(a, n=4)
Out[43]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])

In [44]: sliding_windows(a, n=5)
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

One more with `array-assignment`, which should be good if you need a writable version -

```
def sliding_windows_arrassign(a, n=4):
    pad_length = len(a) + n + 1
    width = n + 1
    p = np.zeros((width,pad_length),dtype=a.dtype)
    p[:,:len(a)] = a
    return p.ravel()[:-n-1].reshape(width,-1)
```

#### Benchmarking on larger arrays

1) `100` elements and similar `n` :

```
In [101]: a = np.arange(1,101)

In [102]: %timeit sliding_windows(a, n=len(a)+1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.6 µs per loop

In [103]: %timeit sliding_windows_arrassign(a, n=len(a)+1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.63 µs per loop

# @Julien's soln
In [104]: %%timeit
     ...: n = len(a)+1
     ...: m = np.tile(np.hstack((a,np.zeros(n+1))),n+1)[:(n+len(a))*(n+1)]
     ...: m.shape = (n+1, n+len(a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15 µs per loop
```

2) ~`5000` elements and similar `n` :

```
In [82]: a = np.arange(1,5000)

In [83]: %timeit sliding_windows(a, n=len(a)+1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 µs per loop

In [84]: %timeit sliding_windows_arrassign(a, n=len(a)+1)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.9 ms per loop

# @Julien's soln
In [91]: %%timeit
    ...: n = len(a)+1
    ...: m = np.tile(np.hstack((a,np.zeros(n+1))),n+1)[:(n+len(a))*(n+1)]
    ...: m.shape = (n+1, n+len(a))
10 loops, best of 3: 34.3 ms per loop
```

`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` would have a constant runtime irrespective of the array length owing to the memory efficiency discussed earlier.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. I have to figure out what you did with np.r_ and the stride calls, but this does what I want as far as I can tell.

Comment: I get `TypeError: as_strided() got an unexpected keyword argument 'writeable'`...

Comment: @Julien What's your NumPy version?

Comment: @Divakar: what's the benefit of creating a non-writable array?

Comment: @Jonas The huge performance benefit, which comes from the memory efficiency and that's because we are working with `views`, so no extra memory is needed for the output. The timings as shown in this post for large arrays should give some idea. For a writable one, we need `.copy()` and that's a significant overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another more concise one, not sure how it compares for efficiency though:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])

n = 4
m = np.tile(np.hstack((a,np.zeros(n+1))),n+1)[:(n+len(a))*(n+1)]
m.shape = (n+1, n+len(a))
```

Efficiency comparison (writable version):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100)
n = 100

def Julien(a, n=4):
    m = np.tile(np.hstack((a,np.zeros(n+1))),n+1)[:(n+len(a))*(n+1)]
    m.shape = (n+1, n+len(a))
    return m

def Divakar(a, n=4):
    length = len(a) + n
    width = n + 1
    z_pad = np.zeros(n,dtype=a.dtype)
    ac = np.r_[z_pad, a, z_pad]
    s = ac.strides[0]    
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(ac[n:], shape=(width, length), strides=(-s,s))

%timeit Julien(a)
%timeit Divakar(a)

18.1 µs ± 333 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
23.4 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. I won't know if it's efficient enough until I code it into the raspberry pi and my group tests whether or not it's fast enough for our purposes, but it's good to have options. The only thing I've noticed different so far is that your output defaulted into a float, even though I entered an integer. However, this shouldn't be an issue as I'm expecting to work in float/double anyways.

Comment: @AlexHu What's your typical length of `a` and typical value for `n` for your actual use-case?

Comment: I am not sure yet. Specifically, I'm building this to collect information from a analog to discrete signal sent by a speaker. I'm expecting a to be in the 100s, but I have to check with a live test to find out. Similarly, the timestep is something that I have to personally adjust for the best performance. Right now I'm guessing in the magnitude of 10s. However, since the speaker sends out a chirp that is supposed to reflected back from 2 meters (group project is sonar), I'm working with fractions of a second in order to retrieve the right information. That's why I'm concerned with efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inbuilt (sort of) method. Not the fastest, though:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg as sl
>>> def f_pp(a, n=4):
...     pad = np.zeros((n,), a.dtype)
...     return sl.toeplitz(*map(np.concatenate, ((a[:1], pad), (a, pad))))
... 
>>> f_pp(np.array([1,2,3]))
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```