# How to apply a custom function to specific columns in a matrix in PyTorch

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of size [150, 182, 91], the first part is just the batch size while the matrix I am interested in is the 182x91 one.

I need to run a function on the 182x91 matrix for each of the 50 dimensions separately.

I need to get a diagonal matrix stripe of the 182x91 matrix, and the function I am using is the following one (based on my previous question: [Getting diagonal matrix stripe automatically in numpy or pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982746/getting-diagonal-matrix-stripe-automatically-in-numpy-or-pytorch)):

```
 def stripe(a):

    i, j = a.size()
    assert (i >= j)

    out = torch.zeros((i - j + 1, j))
    for diag in range(0, i - j + 1):
        out[diag] = torch.diag(a, -diag)
    return out
```

The `stripe` function expects a matrix of size IxJ and can't deal with the 3rd dimension.

So when I run this:

```
some_matrix = x # <class 'torch.autograd.variable.Variable'> torch.Size([150, 182, 91])
get_diag = stripe(some_matrix)
```

I get this Error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

If I just try to skip the first dimension by doing `x, i, j = a.size()`, 
I get this: `RuntimeError: invalid argument 1: expected a matrix or a vector at`

I am still on PyTorch 0.3.1. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the stripe function over the first dimension of your tensor using `torch.unbind` as

```
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: def strip(a):
   ...:     i, j = a.size()
   ...:     assert(i >= j)
   ...:     out = torch.zeros((i - j + 1, j))
   ...:     for diag in range(0, i - j + 1):
   ...:         out[diag] = torch.diag(a, -diag)
   ...:     return out
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [3]: a = torch.randn((182, 91)).cuda()

In [5]: output = strip(a)

In [6]: output.size()
Out[6]: torch.Size([92, 91])

In [7]: a = torch.randn((150, 182, 91))

In [8]: output = list(map(strip, torch.unbind(a, 0)))

In [9]: output = torch.stack(output, 0)

In [10]: output.size()
Out[10]: torch.Size([150, 92, 91])
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the following error `RuntimeError: copy from Variable to torch.FloatTensor isn't implemented`, as I've said my input is a Variable not a tensor, is there a quick way to change the type? Looks like moving to 0.4 can pay off.

Comment: Yes, it works right away in `0.4.1`. But, if you want to run this on `0.3.1`, the error must be introduced by line `out[diag] = torch.diag(a, -diag)`. You can wrap the creation of `out` with `Variable` as `out = Variable(torch.zeros(i - j + 1, j)))`

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine. Btw, for some reason when I do `j + 1` in your solution, I always get the output length with one element too many. If I don't use the `+1` it seems to work just fine and outputs the proper number of elements. Can you elaborate why you did the `+1`, please?

Comment: Consider the case when the matrix is `n X n`. If you compute `(i - j)` then it will be `0` and the digaonal of the matrix won’t be chosen.

Comment: after adding the code, I am always getting `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (181) must match the size of tensor b (180) at non-singleton dimension 1` error in `torch.autograd.backward` at the end of the epoch iteration, is anything in the code adding some extra parameters to the model that I have to track?

Comment: I found a solution, somehow wrapping that tensor into a Variable in a separate function caused it not be properly tracked. Instead of using Variable in `def stripe`, I used it outside of the function and in the function, I used `out[diag] = torch.diag(a.data, -diag)` to get the data.

Comment: That seems odd! Wrapping the tensor as Variable inside function should not be a problem. Nonetheless, it isn't required anymore as  PyTorch 0.4.0 have merged tensor and Variable

Comment: This solution was making my model train about 20 times longer than before. I've got another solution that calculates the stripe directly on a batch matrix. See my answer for more. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this without using `stack` and `unbind`, by computing the diagonal stripe directly on a batch matrix:

```
def batch_stripe(a):
    b, i, j = a.size()
    assert i > j
    b_s, k, l = a.stride()
    return torch.as_strided(a, (b, i - j, j), (b_s, k, k+1))
```

For more, refer to:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/optimizing-diagonal-stripe-code/17777/5